# On the notion of conelike stratified (cs-) space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, perverse-sheaves, sheaf-theory, stratifications

The notion of cs-stratification of a topological space is apparently due to Siebenmann, see also the paper by N. Habegger and L. Saper in the paper ["Intersection cohomology of cs-spaces and Zeeman's filtration"](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01232267),  Invent.Math. (1991).

First I remind its definition and then formulate my question.

**Definition.**
*Let $X$ be a topological space. A filtration $\mathcal{X}$ of $X$ by closed subsets*
$$X=X_n \supset X_{n-1}\supset\dots \supset X_0\supset X_{-1}=\emptyset$$
*is called cs-stratification of dimension $n$ if it satisfies the following properties:*

*(i) The stratum $S_{n-k}:=X_{n-k}\backslash X_{n-k-1}$ is either empty or a $(n-k)$-dimensional topological manifold.*

*(ii) $S_n=X_n\backslash X_{n-1}$ is non-empty.*

*(iii) (Local Normal Triviality) For any $x\in S_{n-k}$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $X$ and a homeomorphism*
\begin{eqnarray}\label{E:1}
U=B\times c(L),\,\,\, (\ast)
\end{eqnarray}
*where $B$ is an open $(n-k)$-dimensional ball, and $c(L)$ is the open cone*
\begin{eqnarray*}
c(L)=L\times [0,1)/(x,0)\sim(x',0),\\
(c(\emptyset)\mbox{ is a point})
\end{eqnarray*}
*on a compact topological space $L$ (called the link). $L$ is assumed to have a filtration $\mathcal{L}$*
$$L=L_{k-1}\supset L_{k-2}\supset \dots\supset L_0\supset L_{-1}=\emptyset$$
*for which the homeomorphism ($\ast$) satisfies*
$$U\cap X_{n-j}=B\times c(L_{k-j-1}).$$

As far as I understand it follows automatically that any subset $L_k\subset L$ is closed. But my question is as follows.

**Question.** It is not explicitly mentioned in the definition that the filtration $\mathcal{L}$ of $L$ is a cs-stratification (by induction on the dimension).
Was this assumption omitted by purpose or it should be added? Does it follow automatically from the other assumptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at Greg Friedman's book:
http://faculty.tcu.edu/gfriedman/IHbook.pdf
CS-sets are discussed in section 2.3. In fact for many purposes it is rather interesting to suppose that the links $L$ are just compact filtered topological spaces and not CS-sets. Deligne's axioms for intersection homology sheaves are easy to verify in this setting where we just suppose that links are compact.

The definition does not imply $L$ is itself a CS-set.

Such a recursive assumption is useful when you want to study pseudomanifolds and Poincaré duality of pseudomanifolds in intersection homology.

Comment: In Siebenmann's "Deformation of Homeomorphisms on Stratified Sets," where he introduces CS sets, he explicitly notes on page 128 that he does not make this assumption. You can still prove a surprising amount about these spaces without such an assumption! (And thanks, David, for referencing my book!)